# Convert formulas to values and remove special characters

Tags: excel, vba

After the vba macro is running only the values sholud be visible into the cells. In addtional all special character #N/A"  should be removed. Everywhere where #N/A stands should then be an empty field.

```
    Dim sh As Worksheet, shOld As Worksheet, shNew As Worksheet, lastR As Long, rngB As Range
   Dim rngBJ As Range, rngBN As Range, lastR2 As Long, lastR3 As Long, arrVlk, iRow As Long, i As Long, l As Long

   iRow = 5 'the row where from the data will be returned
   Set sh = Worksheets("PIV Kunde SO & Status")
   Set shOld = Worksheets("oldStockAge")
   Set shNew = Worksheets("PIV Kunde SO, Vendor & Age")
   
    lastR = sh.Range("B" & sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lastR2 = shOld.Range("B" & sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lastR3 = shNew.Range("B" & sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Set rngB = sh.Range("B" & iRow & ":B" & lastR)
    Set rngBJ = shOld.Range("B5:J" & lastR2)
    Set rngBN = shNew.Range("B2:F" & lastR3)
    
      For l = 2 To 6
        sh.Cells(iRow, l + 2).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(B5," & rngBN.Address(external:=True) & "," & l & ",0)"
    Next l
    sh.Range("D" & iRow, "F" & iRow).AutoFill Destination:=sh.Range("D" & iRow, "F" & lastR)
    
    For i = 7 To 9
        sh.Cells(iRow, i + 1).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(B5," & rngBJ.Address(external:=True) & "," & i & ",0)"
    Next i
    sh.Range("D" & iRow, "I" & iRow).AutoFill Destination:=sh.Range("D" & iRow, "I" & lastR)
```

Comment: Start with `sh.Range("D" & iRow, "I" & lastR).Value = sh.Range("D" & iRow, "I" & lastR).Value`

Comment: So, your code returns what you need, but you only want replacing of `#N/A`  with an empty string (no formula, any more). Is this understanding a correct one?

Comment: @BigBen I am afraid that, in case of `#N/A` error it will return a "#N/A" string...

Comment: If the answer of my above clarification question is 'yes', please test the solution I posted and send some feedback.

Comment: @FaneDuru - I'm pretty sure an `#N/A` error would remain an `#N/A` error value - it would just be hard-coded and not the result of a formula. But, moot point. I was only referencing the first part of the question: "only the values should be visible".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, add to the end of your existing code the next lines:

```
Dim rngNA as Range
On Error Resume Next 'just to avoid a code error in case of no #N/A return...
 set rngNa = sh.Range("D" & iRow, "I" & lastR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)
On Error GoTo 0
If Not rngNA Is Nothing Then rngNA.Value = ""
```

Or try adapting the formula to return an empty string in case of no match, in the next way:

```
    Dim strFormula As String
    For l = 2 To 6
        strFormula = "VLOOKUP(B5," & rngBN.Address(external:=True) & "," & l & ",0)"
        sh.cells(iRow, l + 4).Formula = "=If(ISNA(" & strFormula & "),""""," & strFormula & ")"
   Next l
```

`strFormula` is used only to avoid a big 'sausage' formula... :)

Comment: @Gogi It should not be `rng.Value = ""`, it should be `rngNA.Value = ""`... If it is a matter of typo in your comment, please use `If Not rngNA is Nothing then rngNA.Value = ""`. Maybe, in that specific range there is no any formula error... I thought that it should be and did not check it (in suggested code). In fact, I will adapt it, too. And, in case of any error, you should state which error (error description)... We would understand better what is it about...

Comment: Both works perfect now. FaneDuru you are the VBA guru:-)Well done.Hopefully I won't get banned for saying thank you.

Comment: @Gogi I was not talking about my answers... I only wanted to inform that you can vote up an answer, if you like it, even if it does not answer **your question**...